# Replace and print characters from 2d list python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 2d list (array) in python that I am trying to print to the console with different characters.

Array:

```
maze_a = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1],
[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1],
[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1],
[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
[1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1]]
```

Code:

```
    for row in maze_a:
        print(*row)
```

Current Output:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

I am trying to add to my code to change the characters.  I would like the 0's as whitespace and the 1's as *s.

I tried .replace(0, ' ') but I couldn't seem to get it work.

I know this seems easy but I cannot find an answer for the life of me.  Maybe I cannot use the print(*row) or I need to convert to string first (which I tried and failed)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which uses the value in the matrix as in index into another list that holds the desired characters to print. There are other ways to do this, but this is easy to understand.

```
chars = [' ', '*']
for row in maze_a:
    for item in row:
        print(chars[item], end=' ')
    print()
```

The resulting printout using your value for `maze_a` is

```
* * * * * * *   * * * * * * * 
*           *   *           * 
*   * * *   *   * * * * *   * 
*   *   *   *           *   * 
*   *   *   * * * * *   *   * 
*   *                   *   * 
* * *   * * * * * * * * *   * 
*           *               * 
*   * * *   *   * * * * * * * 
*   *   *   *               * 
*   *   *   * * * * * * *   * 
*       *       *       *   * 
* * * * *   *   *   *   *   * 
*       *   *   *   *   *   * 
*   * * *   * * *   *   *   * 
*                   *       * 
* * * * * * * * *   * * * * *
```

In this solution, there is an invisible space printed at the end of each line, which probably does not matter to you. A little more work can prevent that space.

Comment: Why the downvote? The problem is well-posed, the OP did some work of his own, and I gave a complete answer with an explanation.

Comment: Thanks Rory!  This is great simple solution. However I am trying to figure out what part of it determines if it is a 1 or a 0?

Comment: Nevermind I get it now. Thank you! This is very efficient.